# Django m2m field remove method not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name="voters")
    voters_voted = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True, related_name="voted")
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    in_favour = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    against = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        queryset = self.game.players
        for player in queryset:
            self.voters.add(player)
```

And a voting form, which has the following form_valid method:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        game = Game.objects.get(id=foo)
        vote = Vote.objects.get(id=bar)
        if form.cleaned_data['choice'] == 'Y':
            vote.in_favour += 1
        else form.cleaned_data['choice'] == 'N':
            vote.against += 1

        vote.voters.remove(self.request.user) #This line doesn't work
        vote.voters_voted.add(self.request.user)
        vote.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The purpose of this is to keep track of which users have voted, which are eligible to vote, and what the voting is (in favour/against).

Everything in this code works perfectly, except for the line that removes users from the voters group when they submit the form (`vote.voters.remove(self.request.user)`). The following line, that adds the user to the voted group (`vote.voters_voted.add(self.request.user)`) works perfectly.

I have tried putting a second `vote.save()` in between these two lines, but that didn't make any difference. I don't understand why the second line works, but the first doesn't!

Comment: It's just failing silently?

Comment: @SachinKukreja Yes, it doesn't throw any errors, but if I check the db, it has succeeded in adding the user to voters_voted, but it has not removed them from voters

Comment: Could it be because that `vote`'s `game` relation has `request.user` in its `players`?

Comment: @SachinKukreja That does seem to be it... Voting triggers the save method on the vote, which is weird.

Comment: No, voting does not. `vote.save` call is.

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the object, before removing the `user`.

**Solution**:

```
vote.save() # call this first, because it adds the game players which could include the user you are removing
vote.voters.remove(self.request.user)
```